# scrpage2 - Chapter and Section on two lines in header?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

Here is a the beginning of my code :

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{scrpage2} %head-foot koma
\deftripstyle{fancy}[0pt][0.4pt]
          {\leftmark}{}{\thepage}
          {Nom du document}{}{Lieu} %page style for right pages (odd)
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

...which works like a charm, header/footer respect the `twoside` option by changing the display on odd/even pages.

Question :
**As I have a lot of sections and chapters in my document, and both are useful to situate the page, I'd like to have both of them displayed on the inner header, on 2 lines, how can I do that?**

I have tried this: (which doesn't work)

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{scrpage2} %head-foot koma
\deftripstyle{fancy}[0pt][0.4pt]
            {\leftmark \newline \rightmark}{}{\thepage}
            {Nom du document}{}{Lieu} %page style for right pages (odd)
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution.

First of all, if you have an up-to-date KOMA-script bundle, use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `scrpage2`.

Instead of using `\deftripstyle` we will use `\defpagestyle`:

The line

```
\setlength{\headheight}{22pt}
```

is to increase a little the room for the header.

MWE (replace `scrlayer-scrpage` with `scrpage2` if you have an old KOMA/script bundle)

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} %head-foot koma
\setlength{\headheight}{22pt}
\defpagestyle{fancy}{%
  {\thepage\hfill\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}\raggedleft\leftmark \\ \rightmark\end{minipage}}
  {\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\linewidth}\raggedright\leftmark \\ \rightmark\end{minipage}\hfill\thepage}
  {\hfill}
}{%
  {Lieu\hfill Nom du document}
  {Nom du document\hfill Lieu}
  {\hfill}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Edit : so far your answer is the best to me, because it allows me to have the correct alignement (odd-even dependent) on header, thank.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{scrpage2} %head-foot koma
\deftripstyle{fancy}[0pt][0.4pt]
  {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\leftmark \\ \rightmark\end{tabular}}{}{\thepage}
  {Nom du document}{}{Lieu} %page style à droite (impair)

\addtolength{\headheight}{11pt} % avoid overfull box

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Un titre}

\section{Encore}

\kant[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `scrlayer-scrpage` a tabular is still better:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} %head-foot koma
\defpagestyle{fancy}{%
  {\thepage\hfill\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\leftmark \\ \rightmark\end{tabular}}
  {\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\leftmark \\ \rightmark\end{tabular}\hfill\thepage}
  {}
}{%
  {Nom du document}{}{Lieu} %page style à droite (impair)
}
\setlength{\headheight}{27.2pt} % avoid overfull box

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Un titre}

\section{Encore}

\kant[1-12]

\end{document}
```

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

However, I don't see why duplicating information in this way: you'll have the same information in facing pages, in places very near to each other.

Comment: Thanks, but alignement isn't correct on even pages, and if you change it, it won't be correct on odd pages.

Comment: @V.B. You didn't tell what alignment you want.

Comment: My bad, I assumed it was obvious that I wanted to keep an alignement on the line extremity.

Comment: @V.B. See my update and the final note.

Comment: Thank you for the update, after all I like it, because using minipage feels like using an unappropriate tool that was design for other purposes (page tool). To respond to your last comment, I would say that this layout was chosen based on 2 rules, I wanted pages number outside top, and I wanted Section/Chapter top, but I will consider changing the layout, maybe Sec/Chap outside top, and page° outside bottom, I don't know yet. The point is now I know how to change it, many thanks.
I have 2 other questions, directly related to this context, should I open another topic, or can I ask it there?

Comment: The usage of `\defpagestyle` is not correct. Take a look at the footer.

Comment: Yes I just saw it too, I didn't notice at first. I will do with your sintax karlkoeller (inner/outer correct definition for footer), and with tabular.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the pair of lines in a `\parbox`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,headlines=2.5]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police

\newcommand{\oddevenlap}[1]{\ifodd\value{page}\rlap{#1}\else\llap{#1}\fi}

\deftripstyle{fancy}[0pt][0.4pt]
            {\parbox[b]{0pt}{\strut\oddevenlap{\leftmark}\\
                             \oddevenlap{\rightmark\strut}}}{}{\thepage}
            {Nom du document}{}{Lieu} %page style à droite (impair)

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Here on even pages (*Updated*) I have used `\llap` to put the `\leftmark` in a box of zero width with the mark sticking out to the left, so that I don't need to decide on a value for the width of the `\parbox`.  The `\strut` commands give this box uniform height and depth and usual circumstances.  I have passed an increased `headlines` option to the documentclass to help the page layout.

Comment: This works bad in odd pages.

Comment: @karlkoeller Oops - switching now added, many thanks.